# Ajax is not able to get the proper response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using an AJAX call to to get the response from the server. I can see that in our logs, server is responding the proper data, e.g.:

```
" <xmltag> " + result + " </xmltag>"
```

After we get the result we are using below snippet:

```
if (null != result && result.indexOf('<xmltag>') > -1) {
    var temp = result.split(' ');
    ppdTime = temp[1];
}
```

Most of the time (almost 99%) it works fine. We have started noticing that few instances we are not able to get the proper response even when we can see that server did responded with valid data.

Please not that we are using JavaScript http_request = new XMLHttpRequest(); to send and receive the request.

Did anyone come across this kind of issue? Can this be possible that split(' ') won't work in some browsers?

Can it possible that indexof can fail in case of some OS/browser combinations?

Below are the user agent we have received in case of failures.

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)   --- IE8 XP
>
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.5; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; IPH 1.1.21.4019; BRI/2)   --IE7 XP
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)   IE8 Windows7
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)    IE9 Windows 7
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B554a Safari/9537.53 Safari 7 iOS 7 Tablet

Comment: javascript is one word

Comment: Where is this script failing? What is the proper response and what do you get?

Comment: Why would you use indexOf, split, etc. on an XML document? Why not use DOM? That's exactly what's it was invented for.

Comment: To make my previous point clear, in your example, you have a " " (space) right before your XML tag. Things like that can easily break your parser. Never parse XML by hand, use DOM. Period.